# Autoresizing subview to text length inside NSCollectionView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an NSCollectionView. My example subviews are simple, basically a Label with a box around them.

[image]

I would like my subviews to resize their width to fit the label length. For example, if we have "banana", "tomato" and "pig", i.e.,

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.listObjArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"banana", @"tomato", @"pig", nil];

}
```

the CollectionView (bound to Array Controller bound to listObjArray) should show

> [banana] [tomato] [pig]

instead of

> [bana] [toma] [pig ]

[image]

How can I do this? As a bonus, I would like the subview to increase in size no larger than the CollectionView width, so that I have I have a really long text, I would end up with

```
[thisisareallysuperlongkindofst...]
[banana] [tomato] [pig]
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible with a `NSCollectionView` (but if anyone knows better, please correct me). The collection view assumes are the cells are exactly the same size, and places the cells in a fixed rectangular grid.

Comment: @aapierce you could be right on this - at least at one point this was the case: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Feb/msg00682.html :(